# how can I remove a facebook login view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to remove a facebook view controller that I created. Basically, the showFBLoginView method that initializes the view controller is the App Delegate and called within a GameOver layer.

```
-(void)showFBLoginView {

   facebookViewController = [[FacebookViewController alloc] init];
   self.facebookViewController = facebookViewController;

   // Set loginUIViewController as root view controller
   [[self window] setRootViewController:facebookViewController];

   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   [self.facebookViewController activateButton:@"Facebook Connect"];
         .
         .
         .
   }
```

The activateButton method within the facebookViewController.m class:

```
-(void)activateButton:(NSString*)buttonText {    
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

fbConnectButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
fbConnectButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width/2 - 50*(screenSize.width/480) , screenSize.height/2, screenSize.width/4, screenSize.height/12);
[fbConnectButton setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
fbConnectButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[fbConnectButton setTitleColor:[UIColor brownColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

[fbConnectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:fbConnectButton];
```

}

I tried to remove the faceboookViewController in the following way. This was done within the App Delegate.

```
  [[self window] removeFromSuperview];
```

But it's not working. What is the right way to remove the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
 faceboookViewController *fbViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

StoryboardID is StoryboardID of faceboookViewController.
you can dismiss if you present it.